# How to allow hashing functions returning 64 bit integers for a HashSet

Tags: c#, hash, hashset

I have a 4-dimensional Point class with each of the 4 values being integers ranging from 0 to about 1000, so a hashing function on such a Point would return values from 0 to 1000^4, and thus would need 40 bits if my maths is correct. However, the GetHashCode method (hashing function) I have to override can only return 32 bit integers; not enough for the 40 bit integers.

My end goal is to use a HashSet to check for duplicate 4D points in a list by going through all of them and adding them to the HashSet (if there is already an element at that index then the point has already been seen and is a duplicate). 
This means that there would be as many indexes in the hashset as there are values of the hashed points, which would be 1000^4 different indexes.

The realistic number of points that will be put into the hashset is anywhere up to 8,000. Every time a point is attempted to be inserted into the hashset, 0 or 1 collisions are expected (never any more).

Please excuse my possible misunderstanding of HashSets. I am not too bothered about run time with my algorithm, but I was experimenting to see how low its 'big oh' time cost would be.

Comment: HashSet requires you to use a 32-bit hash. It has no trouble whatsoever with unequal set elements with the same hash. An obvious implementation is return v1 ^ (v2 << 8) ^ (v3 << 15) ^ (v4 << 22), it will be close to ideal. Don't forget to provide an Equals implementation as well.

Comment: Remember, the by-design purpose of a hash function is to *reduce collisions*, not to *eliminate them entirely*. There are far, far more than 4 billion short strings, and yet somehow string hash tables do just fine with a 32 bit hash. It's because collisions are rare enough.  Hashing is not a substitute for equality checking; rather, it speeds up equality checking because you only have to do full equality checking *on the collisions*.

Comment: @EricLippert With collisions it would move from O(1) to O(n) though I think, and I was just hoping that the slight increase from 32 to 40 bits would still have some O(1) solution.

Comment: @TeeMee123 It's O(n) where n is *the average number of collisions per object, not *the size of the collection*.  The average number of collisions per object is almost certainly a constant number in your case, and a very small constant at that, which is what makes hashsets have O(1) operations, in practice.

Comment: @TeeMee123: I'm not following your train of thought here.  You've omitted a bunch of very important information from your question, namely: **how many points are in your collection, and how many of them do you think will exactly collide**?  That will determine the performance characteristics of your proposed duplicate detection.

Comment: Think about it this way. Suppose we have a four-dimensional int vector where each value ranges from 0 to 65535. Fortunately that is the exact size that fits into a C# `char`, so we represent our 4-vector as a string with four characters in it. **We don't need a 16*4 bit hash to make a hash table that contains these strings**. Why would we?

Comment: Also I don't understand why you're saying that a hash table will use up too much memory. If you have so many points that you cannot fit them all into memory at once, and you still want to detect collisions, that's no problem. You partition your 4-d vector space into 16 parts in the obvious way, then you do 16 passes over your data set, each time extracting the members of that part.  Then you do collision detection *just in that part*, and collate the results. That way you only ever have 1/16th max of the points in memory at once.

Comment: If one of your parts itself has too many points in it then you partition *it* into 16 parts and repeat the process.  And so on.  But again, I think you are omitting some very important information from your question, and that is preventing you from getting a good answer.

Comment: @EricLippert I have edited the question quite a bit again, I hope it makes more sense now and that it has enough information about my problem

Comment: OK, I've read your updates and I cannot for the life of me figure out what you are asking here.  8000 points is *nothing*. The probability of at least one 32 bit hash collision in 8000 points, assuming the hash function is well distributed, is approximately one in 200, so 199 out of every 200 times you run this you will get *zero* collisions. I really don't understand why you're even asking this question. Correctly implement GetHashCode and Equals, and start stuffing points into your hash set. You'll very quickly find the duplicates.

Comment: @EricLippert what my question boiled down to was whether or not there was some way of changing the size. In my mind any information explaining why I needed that done (numbers of collisions, numbers of points) was irrelevant. In hindsight, I probably should have left out the reason why I wanted it to use 64-bit int.

Comment: I think you are *fundamentally* misunderstanding something here. *The whole point is that the hash function maps 40 bits (or 100 bits or 1000000 bits or whatever) of data to 32 bits*. That's a *feature*, not a *problem*. That's the feature that gives you the speedup! What are you really asking here?

Comment: I think you would strongly benefit from a crash course in hash sets, how they work, and why hash code have to have the properties that they do. Fortunately I have written such a crash course. Start here: https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/  and then to understand the probability of a collision given 8000 samples, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions/

Comment: I think I've put my finger on the fundamental problem; it's here: "*This means that there would be as many indexes in the hashset as there are values of the hashed points, which would be 1000^4 different indexes.*" No, that doesn't follow at all.  Suppose we decide that the average bucket loading factor of the hash table should be 4.  You're adding 8000 points. So we create an array of around 2000 hash chains, and if the hash is well distributed, each one of them will have around 4 items on it, so the search time is O(4) = a constant.

Comment: @EricLippert ok, what I'm asking fundamentally is how to get this code I have to work. The reason it wont is because i have a GetHashCode function to override to return an integer between zero and 1000^4, however that number exceeds the limits of the int type which it has to return, so I get an overflow exception.

Comment: @EricLippert by the way you are answering my comments so quickly I have been responding to comments further up

Comment: That is an *entirely different question than the one you asked*. On SO we call this an "XY problem". You have some *completely crazy idea* about how to solve your problem, and you ask a question about the crazy idea, leading everyone to say "that's crazy".  If your question is "how do I make a well-distributed hash code for a vector of four small integers" then *ask that question*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163754/discussion-between-teemee123-and-eric-lippert).

Answer (score 2):

If you override `Equals`, then the `HashSet` will still ensure uniqueness. The hashing is essentially an optimization so it doesn't have to compare every element of the set.

Unless you have concrete requirements for how fast your program needs to run, you should be just fine using a trivial `GetHashCode` implementation like this:

```
int GetHashCode()
{
  return Tuple.create(this.a, this.b, this.c, this.d).GetHashCode();
}
```

If you have tried that and it still isn't enough (or you are doing this for fun), then you can try making your own hash set implementation using longs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 2^64 of memory?  Hash codes are supposed to map objects onto an array small enough to fit in memory.  (`HashSet` will reduce the number of bits in the hash even further, for this reason)

Just return a 32-bit hash code, and make sure that your equality comparison function (`override bool object.Equals(object)`) is working right.  `HashSet` will do an equality check when the hash matches, in order to handle hash collisions.